# Array push só funciona dentro do callback

Tags: array, node.js, array-push

Estou tentando atualizar um array com valores retornados pelo mongoose. Mas o array retorna vazio. Segue o trecho do código:

```js
let y = [];
Vendas.countDocuments(
  { dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }},
    function(err, os) {
      y.push(os);
    }
  );
```

Se dou `console.log(y)` dentro do callback, tenho os valores. Se executo logo após o `countDocuments`, me retorna um array vazio.

Alguém saberia dizer o que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece por conta de problemas com o caráter assíncrono do callback. Nesse caso, você deve usar promises em conjunto com [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas):

```js
async countDoucments() {
   const numeroDeDocumentos = await Vendas.count({ dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }}).exec();
   return numeroDeDocumentos;
}
```

Assim, ao chamar a função assíncrona `countDocuments`, você receberá uma promise que contém o número de documentos.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta João, mas ainda não consegui pegar o valor da variável e passar para o array. Tentei de várias formas, segue uma delas: `  async function docs() {
    const numDocs = await Vendas.countDocuments({ dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }}).exec();
    return numDocs;
  }
  docs().then(function (err,n) {
    y.push(n);
  });
`

Comment: É preciso compreender a diferença entre trabalho assíncrono e trabalho síncrono. Nesse caso por exemplo, dentro de outra função async, você pode fazer: `y.push(await countDocuments())`